# Why does Matlab change LineWidth and LineStyle of already plotted lines after plotting a patch?

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

When I plot several lines in Matlab using `plot3` with the following format:

```
    plot3([x1 x2], [y1 y2], [z1 z2], 'LineWidth', 2, 'LineStyle','--');
```

and plot a patch afterward using `patch` like this:

```
    p = patch(x, y, z, 'k');
    set(p, 'EdgeColor', 'g', 'FaceColor', 'none', 'LineWidth', 3, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.7)
```

'LineWidth' and 'LineStyle' of already plotted lines get changed slightly as shown by the following figures (the first figure shows lines before plotting patch and the second figure shows the change after plotting patch, the green lines). Could you please tell me what is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your `set` command reset the global properties of the axes. You should apply properties to each line, instead of the axes;

```
ahs = findall(gca,'type','line')
set(ahs(1), 'LineWidth', 2, 'LineStyle','--');
set(ahs(2), 'EdgeColor', 'g', 'FaceColor', 'none', 'LineWidth', 3, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.7);
```

Comment: I don't think so. I think it sets only properties of the patch 'set(p, ...)'. Your suggestion is not applicable because the third line of your script doesn't set the properties of the patch.